# Difference of passing argument to std::thread, C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

A quote from [Nikolai Josuttis - Standard Library C++11](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1514092/files/0321623215_TOC.pdf):

> Detached threads can easily become a problem if they use nonlocal resources. The problem is that
>   you lose control of a detached thread and have no easy way to find out whether and how long it runs.
>   Thus, make sure that a detached thread does not access any objects after their lifetime has ended. For
>   this reason, passing variables and objects to a thread by reference is always a risk. Passing arguments
>   by value is strongly recommended.

So further the author explains, that even if you pass a reference as a function argument to a thread, it still passes by value, so you must indicate the reference with `std::ref`.

I have these questions, see the code below:

```
void f(std::vector<int> V){...}
void g(std::vector<int>& V){...}

std::vector<int> V;

std::thread t1(f, V);
std::thread t2(f, std::ref(V));
std::thread t3(g, V);
std::thread t4(g, std::ref(V));
```

What are the differences in these 4 lines? Which lines are equivalent?
I am not joining or detaching thread, it's not about that, it's about the ways of passing the function argument.

Comment: Have you tried to run it? I believe modifying the value inside of the thread and printing it would show the difference perfectly (launch one by one).

Comment: Well, one of those will be ill-formed on a standard compliant compiler, I can tell you that.

Comment: @StoryTeller I would think so too, so I'm not at all surprised it actually still compiles with MS tool chain (CL 19.00.24215.1).

Comment: @WhozCraig - It's that damn extension that allows binding non-const lvalue reference to rvalues.

Comment: @StoryTeller ya. that's generally the very first thing I turn off on new projects. neglected to in this case. silly me.

Comment: @Eduard, the question is "are you detaching or joining these threads?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `t1`:

This simply passes a copy of `V` to the thread.

#### `t2`:

Similarly to `t1`, a copy of `V` is passed to the thread, but the actual copy is made in the called thread instead of the caller thread. This is an important distinction because should `V` be altered or cease to exist by the time the thread begins, you will end up with either a different vector or Undefined Behavior.

#### `t3`:

This should fail to compile as the thread will *move* the vector into the LValue reference, which is supposed to be illegal.

#### `t4`:

This passes the vector by reference to the thread. Any modifications to the passed reference will be applied to `V`, provided that proper synchronisation is performed, of course.

Comment: t2 and t1 are completely different.

Comment: @T.C. I was under the impression that the exception requirements of the conversion process for the thread arguments having to be in the caller thread implied that the copy would have to be made in the caller thread, and then the result moved into `f` once the actual thread starts, is that not correct?

Comment: As usual @T.C. is correct: https://ideone.com/2h58iM (though I'm not sure what I've missed here exactly), I'll ammend the answer.